# I am going to dance to Baby Shark

Tags: grammar, prepositions

He has a dance performance this Sunday and I asked him:

- "What's the name of the song you are going to dance ***to***?"

He replied:

> "I am going to dance Baby Shark."
>
> "I am going to dance ***to*** Baby Shark."

In the question we use "**dance to**", so in the answer, should we also use "**dance to**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.

"**[dance to something](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dance+to)**" means "*to respond to music or rhythm with dancing*"

You will need "**to**" in both the *question* and the *answer*.